# hbase rest api start error

Tags: rest, hbase

I am trying to start the rest API on our hbase installation but keep getting the following error, even when specifying the port.

```
 # hbase rest start --p 8087

java.net.BindException: Port in use: 0.0.0.0:8085

at 
org.apache.hadoop.hbase.http.HttpServer.openListeners(HttpServer.java:1014)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.http.HttpServer.start(HttpServer.java:950)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.http.InfoServer.start(InfoServer.java:90)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.rest.RESTServer.main(RESTServer.java:248)
 Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:437)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:429)
    at 
   sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:223)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:74)
    at 

   org.mortbay.jetty.nio.SelectChannelConnector.open(SelectChannel
   Connector.java:216)
    at 

 org.apache.hadoop.hbase.http.HttpServer.openListeners(HttpServer.java:1009)
    ... 3 more
```

Answer (score 0):

REST port (`--p` option) is 8080. 8085 - is port linked as  `hbase.rest.info.port` (from config).

Use `--infoport 8087` argument to modify it.

Comment: thank you so much for responding. Still getting an error:  [main] mortbay.log: failed Server@5a709816: java.net.BindException: Address already in use
Exception in thread "main" java.net.BindException: Address already in use
....  Does this have anything to do with other applications accessing hbase using the java library?